# Find the unique sum of integers from an dynamic array of numbers

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, windows, list

I am facing a very difficult situation, suppose I have a array of dynamic numbers. The condition is the array may contain 10 numbers to 20 numbers. It can contain 10, 12, 14, ... to 20 integers. Now based on the ArrayList.Count(), I am going to choose 3(if array contains 10 integers) to 6 (if array contain 20 integers) numbers out of this array, and add those numbers. say that number is "X".

Now I have to check if there exist any three integers in the list whose sum is equal to X, if its equal, then again I have to repeat the same procedure until I find a unique sum from the list.

So how can I do it? The best part is all the numbers in the array is unique, there is no repeat of the numbers in the array.

> First Idea

I though of one idea, for 3 numbers, Suppose I generate a unique number.

```
foreach (var i in List) // values of i = 1, 5, 8 (Assume)
{
    sum += listOfUniqueIntegers[i];
}
```

// Fix the first element as List[i]

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count()-2; i++)
{
   // Fix the second element as List[j]
   for (int j = i+1; j < List.Count()-1; j++)
   {
       // Now look for the third number
       for (int k = j+1; k < List.Count(); k++)
       {
           if (List[i] + List[j] + List[k] == sum)
           {
             // Here I will again create one more unique value  
             // and assign it to sum and repeat i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

           }
       }
   }
}
```

But the problem with this approach is its time complexity os n^3 so if I have to generate a sum from 6 numbers when List size is 20, it will be n^6, which is not expected.

> Second idea

I though I can sort the List, but then what logic shall I use to choose 3 integers so that it's sum is unique in the List.

Lets say I sort the list and choose three smallest number or choose from the sorted list 3rd 3+1=4 th and 3+2=5th element, and `sum=List[3]+List[4]+List[5];` 
this is also not expected, any pattern to choose three numbers is not suggested. It should be randomly chosen and the sum should be unique.

So I am not getting any idea to generate a optimal solution for this.

Can anybody please help me.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure there is an unbiased way to find the unique sum that avoids calculating every single combination and randomly choosing a unique one. Any shortcut or smart trick like Amir's answer  is bound to be biased.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the 3 largest numbers.

Comment: Why the distnction? It seems to me that *always* choosing the 3 largest will do the trick. Otherwise, what happens if you have both positive and negative numbers?

Comment: @InBetween You are right, I had another restriction in my mind. Updated.

Comment: Smallest numbers or three largest numbers are not expected scenario, I updated my questions, even lets say I choose any number 4, then I choose 4+1, and next 4+2 element, this is also not expected. It should be random

Comment: @Debhere If you want a deterministic algorithm, in anycase it uses a scenario which lead to a pattern. Otherwise you can just generate every single combination and choose one of the desired answers randomly.

Comment: But if I generate all the possible combination numbers and then find the unique, time complexity will be high. After sorting the List, I am searching any optimal way.

Comment: @Debhere That's what I'm saying. Once you are using some deterministic algorithm, like sorting your numbers, you are biasing your final result, so your answers are going to have a pattern.

Comment: @Amir Thanks, will update when I find some unique way to do it. Thanks for your time and answers